# Solve the equation $ A\cap X=B $ where $ A,B,X $ are sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $ E $ be a set and $ A,B $ two nonempty subsets of $ E $.
Find the subset $ X $ of $ E $ satisfying
$$A \cap X = B. $$

I used the fact that if such nonempty subset $ X $ exists then necessarily
$$B= A\cap X \subset X$$
and
$$B=A \cap X \subset A$$
to conclude that
$$B\subset A \text{ and } B \subset X$$
from here i think there are a lot of cases to distinguish.
any help will be so appreciated.

Comment: The equation $A\cap X=B$ is solvable only if $B\subseteq A$. In this case $X=B$ provides a solution.

Comment: If there is a solution, then $B$ will be a solution.

Comment: $B \subset X$ is not a condition because $X$ is unknown. The only condition to make equation compatible is $B \subset A$.

Comment: Notice that :
$$X = (X \cap A) \cup (X \cap \bar{A})$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C$ denote any arbitrary subset of $A^{c}$.  That is, $A$ and $C$ are disjoint.

Under the assumption that $B \subseteq A$, you can simply set $X$ to equal $B \cup C$.

If $X$ contains any element inside of $A$, other than what is in $B$, then the constructed set $A \cap X$ will not equal $B$.

Since $A$ and $C$ are disjoint, appending $C$ to $X$ does not alter the constructed set $A \cap X$.